# NSLocalizedStringFromTable doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I'm trying to use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` but with no results. I've got created `Profile.strings` file, clicked localized, in project settings I add Polish and English languages, so my file has 2 "files" inside and I typed the same strings with other values but when I switch languages and restart app there is still one localization used (Polish).

Profile.strings in Xcode:

```
Profile.strings
    Profile.strings (Polish)
    Profile.strings (English)
```

Polish:

```
"fullName.placeholder" = "Imie i nazwisko";

"emailAddress.placeholder" = "Adres email";

"phoneNumber.placeholder" = "Numer telefonu";
```

English:

```
"fullName.placeholder" = "Full name";

"emailAddress.placeholder" = "Email address";

"phoneNumber.placeholder" = "Phone number";
```

To get value I call:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"fullName.placeholder", @"Profile", @"");
```

Any time I call this I've got value from `Profile.strings (Polish)`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try again by removing app from device/simulator and relaunch the xcode

Comment: just for more understanding read this http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/04/user-interface-strings-in-cocoa.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+CocoaWithLove+%28Cocoa+with+Love%29

Comment: I know how `NSLocalizedString()` works, but I don't know why `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()` doesn't work.

Comment: @freenalcer, Thanks! `Reset Content and Settings`. Please add answer in separated post and I will mark it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to **Reset Content and Settings** of simulator it will work (:

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're not changing the language correctly. Try doing it in code. Like this:

```
- (void) setLanguage:(NSString*) l{
    for (NSString *language1 in [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]) {
        NSBundle *bundle1 = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language1 ofType:@"lproj"]];
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", language1, NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"left", @"Localizable", bundle1, nil));
    }
    NSBundle *bundle1 = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:l ofType:@"lproj"]];
    /*
   if ([l isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
       bundle1 = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"English" ofType:@"lproj"]];
   }
    */


    if (bundle1 == nil)
        //in case the language does not exists
        [self resetLocalization];
    else
        bundle = bundle1;
    NSMutableArray *langs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]];
    [langs removeObject:l];
    NSMutableArray *newLangs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:l];
    [newLangs addObjectsFromArray:langs];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: newLangs forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
}
```

And then you can do

`[self setLanguage:@"en"];`